# FindView in MxvFrameControl

Tags: android, mvvmcross

I am using a MvxFrameControl to reuse an AddressView in a MyAccountView.

```
<!-- MyAccountView.axml -->
 <MvxFrameControl
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        local:MvxBind="DataContext EditAddressViewModel"
        local:MvxTemplate="@layout/editaddressview"
        android:id="@+id/EditAddressView" />
```

In the android fragment of the MyAccountView, MyAccountFragment, I want to access an EditText included in the layout referenced by the MvxFrameControl.

```
<!-- EditAddressView.axml -->
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/SingleLineEditIconHeight"
        local:MvxBind="Visibility Visibility(IsExpanded)">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/Address1"
            style="@style/EditText"
            android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/MarginMedium"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/MarginSmall"
            android:hint="@string/MyAccount_Address"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:inputType="text"
            local:MvxBind="Text Address1" />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Unfortunately, textViewAddress1 returns null...

```
// MyAccountFragment
View view = this.BindingInflate(this.layoutId, container, false);
var frameControl = view.FindViewById<MvxFrameControl>(Resource.Id.EditAddressView);
var textViewAddress1 = frameControl.FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.Address1);

// textViewAddress1 == null
```

How can I retrieve this view from the MyAccountFragment ?

---

Edit 1:

Seeing the source code of MvxControl, it's obvious that MvxFrameControl is not inflated at this stage:

```
    public MvxFrameControl(int templateId, Context context, IAttributeSet attrs)
        : base(context, attrs)
    {
        _templateId = templateId;

        if (!(context is IMvxLayoutInflater))
        {
            throw Mvx.Exception("The owning Context for a MvxFrameControl must implement LayoutInflater");
        }

        _bindingContext = new MvxAndroidBindingContext(context, (IMvxLayoutInflater)context);
        this.DelayBind(() =>
            {
                if (Content == null && _templateId != 0)
                {
                    Mvx.Trace("DataContext is {0}", DataContext == null ? "Null" : DataContext.ToString());
                    Content = _bindingContext.BindingInflate(_templateId, this);
                }
            });
    }
```

The inflation is placed in an action that is executed only when the DataContext is set (if i understood correctly).
So my question is simple, at what step of the MvxFragment does the data context is set on the MvxFrameControl ?

Comment: Looking around there, see to be The framecontrol doesn't inflate itself until it's data context is set - see https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/blob/3.5/Cirrious/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Binding.Droid/Views/MvxFrameControl.cs#L48 - are you sure it's been inflated when you call FindViewById? (Disclaimer: this is just a guess!)

Answer (score 1):

I found another solution.
After inflating your view, add this code to force the delaybind to occur:

```
BindingContext.DataContext = BindingContext.DataContext;
```

Make sure  `BindingContext.DataContext` is not null :)

Answer (score 0):

Well I had to something quite ugly to make it work...

Since the MvxFrameLayout is only inflated when the DataContext changed, here what I have now in the OnCreateView of my MvxFragment:

```
    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        MvxTrace.Trace("MvxGenericFragment => OnCreateView");
        View ignored = base.OnCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        View view = this.BindingInflate(this.layoutId, container, false);

        var frameControl = view.FindViewById<MvxFrameControl>(Resource.Id.EditAddressView);
        frameControl.BindingContext.DataContextChanged += (sender, args) =>
            {
                var textViewAddress1 = this.View.FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.Address1);
                // textViewAddress1 is not null!
            };
    }
```

If someone has a cleaner way to do it...

Answer (score 0):

A few years later, MvxFrameControl still doesn't inflate the child layout until the DataContext is set. While the solution from Roubachof works, I found it a bit simpler to assign the ViewModel to the BindingContext.DataContext directly in the View code instead of the AXML file.

```
public class HomeView : MvxAppCompatActivity<HomeViewModel>
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.HomeView);
        var frameControl = FindViewById<MvxFrameControl>(Resource.Id.frame_control);

        // This will force the MvxFrameControl to inflate the child layout
        frameControl.BindingContext.DataContext = ViewModel;
        // Depending on your app design, you might use a child ViewModel
        //frameControl.BindingContext.DataContext = ViewModel.ChildViewModel;

        // Locate an EditText inside the MvxFrameControl
        var editText = frameControl.FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.edit_text);
```

Note: In most UI frameworks, I would say that a parent UI element accessing a UI element inside a child element is a bad design, since it breaks encapsulation.  However, since MvvmCross doesn't provide a C# file to back Custom Views, this seems like this may be the best option to add custom functionality.